# Should I consider the 1 in 2^62 possibility of getting the excluded upper-bound when using `Math.random()`?

Tags: javascript, random

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> `Math.random`
>
> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range `[0, 1)`
>   that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive),
>   which you can then scale to your desired range.

But then, it says:

> Note that as numbers in JavaScript are IEEE 754 floating point numbers
>   with round-to-nearest-even behavior, these ranges, excluding the one
>   for `Math.random()` itself, aren't exact, and depending on the bounds
>   it's possible in extremely rare cases (on the order of 1 in 2^62) to
>   calculate the usually-excluded upper bound.

Should I consider those cases? e.g., use...

```
Math.min(max, Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
```

...instead of...

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

...?

Comment: Do *you* think it's worth it?

Comment: *Should* you? Depends: do you care?

Comment: If you're in cryptographic or security applications, yes. Otherwise, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 If you're in crypto, you'd probably have your own pRNG implemented instead of relying on the browser's.

Comment: If you want a serious PRNG in Javascript, check out [Steve Gibson's](https://www.grc.com/otg/uheprng.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you called Math.random() a *billion* times a second, you should expect to encounter this error every 150 years or so. And I'm giving Javascript *way* too much credit for performance. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No. Favor clarity and simplicity over "correctness" and bizarre edge-cases. This more complex code may trip up some poor developer (or maybe the future you) maintaining this code. The chance of that is greater than the 1 in 2^62 chance of Math.random() not working as expected.